# OCaml Async compilation

Tags: ocaml

I have this code

```
open Async.Std;;

let () = print_string "Hello World\n";;
```

and compile with

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -linkpkg -package async -thread ./hello.ml
```

stdout is empty... But if code is just

```
let () = print_string "Hello World\n";;
```

and compile command

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -linkpkg -package async -thread ./hello.ml
```

i have in stdout my "Hello world". What i do wrong? Why first example not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because `open Async.Std` implicitly overrides I/O functions like `print_string` and makes them asynchronous. So, they aren't executed until you start the scheduler.

```
open Async.Std

let () =
  print_string "Hello World\n";              (* schedule "Hello World\n" printing *)
  don't_wait_for (exit 0);                   (* schedule exit from the program *)
  Core.Std.never_returns (Scheduler.go ())   (* run the scheduler *)
```

Read more about Async [there](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/concurrent-programming-with-async.html).